# How to use umlet with asciidoctor-diagram?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, umlet

I have installed correctly Asciidoctor and its extension asciidoctor-diagram because I can generate PlantUML diagram and I would like to do the same with UMLet. According to the [AsciiDoc documentation](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoctor-diagram/#creating-a-diagram), it is possible to insert UMLet diagram inside AsciiDoc document.

So I created a diagram with UMLet and copy/paste it inside my AsciiDoc document like this:

```
[umlet]
...

 <diagram program="umlet" version="14.3.0">
  <zoom_level>10</zoom_level>
  <element>
    <id>UMLUseCase</id>
    <coordinates>
      <x>60</x>
      <y>100</y>
      <w>120</w>
      <h>40</h>
    </coordinates>
    <panel_attributes>Use case 1</panel_attributes>
    <additional_attributes/>
  </element>
  <element>
    <id>UMLActor</id>
    <coordinates>
      <x>230</x>
      <y>80</y>
      <w>60</w>
      <h>110</h>
    </coordinates>
    <panel_attributes>Actor</panel_attributes>
    <additional_attributes/>
  </element>
</diagram>

...
```

And the output was, instead of the expected rendered diagram :

```
It opens the external program umlet but does not render anything :(
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use four dots (....) as a block separator for the diagram.

Changing this rendered the example you provided above.

As I haven't installed umlet in the path, I've added the attribute for this

```
:umlet: C:\...\Umlet\Umlet.exe
```